# Find same objects in both list and set new id in new list java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have Person class which represents worker of company. I am getting all workers of company from database. Admin wants to add some new workers to the company. I want to check if worker exists or not. If exists I will update in db if not I will insert. Check will be based on phoneNumber.

```
@Data
public class Person {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String phoneNumber;
   ...
}
----------

**ServiceClass**
List<Person> workersOfCompany = ..; // get all users of company
List<Person> requestedWorkers = ... ; // requested contacts to be updated/inserted


// Getting users in our system. But in this case id will be always  zero. because requester will not send id.
List<Person> updatable = requestedWorkers.stream()
                .filter(workersOfCompany::contains) // equal method of Person override
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to change this function. I need to get workers which in our system (in workersOfCompany) and set ids to newly created list by getting ids from workersOfCompany.

I can do this by using 2 fors but I want to do this by java 8 streams.

How can I find objects that are in both list and set ids to the objects in new list.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` or `peek` to alter the `Person` items of `requestedWorkers`. Beware of `peek` since it depends on the terminal operation (`collect` in our example). In our case it works however it would be better to use `forEach`

```
    List<Person> updatable = requestedWorkers.stream()
            .filter(workersOfCompany::contains)
            .peek(r -> { // -> better use forEach
                final int indexOf = workersOfCompany.indexOf(r); //here matching equality works with phoneNumber only as you stated
                if (indexOf != -1) {
                    final int id = workersOfCompany.get(indexOf).getId();
                    r.setId(id);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is it efficient way ? Requested can be more than 10.000 users, and company can have 100.000 users

Comment: @Soulmaster Compared to what? To make it more efficient the first thing I would do is **not** to fetch all the company users, why you need to do this? Just work with the users to update/insert. Query your database/directory to just fetch those users, this would be a huge improvement efficiency-wise. However efficiency first appeared in your comment above, your original question was how to make it work using streams and that's what my answer tried to tackle. Have you checked if it works?

Comment: Yes I have checked. Thanks, it works. Because when I use mybatis with oracle db it is impossible use merge into with bulk insert( MERGE INTO  and INSERT ALL).  I know you are definitely right it is not good to fetch all company users.

Answer (score 1):

It could make sense to use `Collectors::partitioningBy` to split the input list of requested workers into existing and new workers.

Also, existing code snippet does not show that the `Person::equals` is overridden to use only the phone number (Lombok `@Data` provides implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` based on all instance fields), so it may be needed to build a map of phones to the ids for the existing workers assuming that the phones are unique per person:

```java
Map<String, Integer> phoneIdMap = workersOfCompany
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getPhoneNumber,
            Person::getId,
            (p1, p2) -> p1 // resolve possible conflicts
        ));

Map<Boolean, List<Person>> split = requestedWorkers
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            p -> phoneIdMap.containsKey(p.getPhoneNumber())
        ));

split.get(Boolean.TRUE) // update ids of existing workers
     .forEach(w -> w.setId(phoneIdMap.get(w.getPhoneNumber())));

split.get(Boolean.FALSE) // insert into DB and fix ids for new workers
     .forEach(w -> w.setId(personRepository.insert(w))); // assuming id is returned
```

---

Similar implementation without creating the intermediate `split` map looks as follows providing that `phoneIdMap` has been created:

```java
requestedWorkers.forEach(
    w -> w.setId(phoneIdMap.getOrDefault(
        w.getPhoneNumber(), personRepository.insert(w)
    ))
);
```

Or, if the ids should only be updated for the existing workers, a filter may be applied:

```java
requestedWorkers
    .stream()
    .filter(w -> phoneIdMap.containsKey(w.getPhoneNumber()))
    .forEach(w -> w.setId(phoneIdMap.get(w.getPhoneNumber())));
```